# How can I determine whether Console.Out has been redirected to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, console

If my program is printing to the console, I perform word-wrapping in a certain way according to Console.WindowWidth by inserting newlines - and this works perfectly.

However if the output of the program is redirected to a file or another program I would like it to skip the word-wrapping. How can I detect when this is the case?

Console.WindowWidth returns the same number in both cases.

**Bonus** points if the solution can distinguish redirected Console.Out from redirected Console.Error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if output is redirected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169591/check-if-output-is-redirected)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

p/invoke `GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))`, or call an innocuous console function like `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` to check for invalid handle error. If you want to know about standard error, use `STD_ERROR_HANDLE`. I believe you can even compare handles returned by `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` and `GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)` to detect stuff like `2>&1`.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly and more future-proof than reflection-based stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

.NET 4.5 adds `Console.IsOutputRedirected` and `Console.IsErrorRedirected`.

Answer (score 8):

While this is a little shady and probably isn't guaranteed to work, you can try this:

```
bool isRedirected;

try
{
    isRedirected = Console.CursorVisible && false;
}
catch
{
    isRedirected = true;
}
```

Calling CursorVisible throws an exception when the console is redirected.

Comment: Seems to work for stdout. Provides no distinction between cases when only stderr, only stdout or both are redirected. Still ok for some use cases though.

Comment: It always worked for me when stdout was redirected, which I would imagine is really the only one that would matter, right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use reflection - a bit grubby but the following will work:

```
static bool IsConsoleRedirected()
{
    var writer = Console.Out;
    if (writer == null || writer.GetType ().FullName != "System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter") return true;
    var fld = writer.GetType ().GetField ("_out", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fld == null) return true;
    var streamWriter = fld.GetValue (writer) as StreamWriter;
    if (streamWriter == null) return true;
    return streamWriter.BaseStream.GetType ().FullName != "System.IO.__ConsoleStream";
}
```

Comment: And how do you make sure it will work in the next version of .NET as well? :)

Comment: That's why it's a bit grubbly. But it's the only option.

Comment: While it does nasty stuff like checking the name of the type of a private field... It's still the best solution so far and others are not much less nasty.

Comment: I think it's an OK technique. You'd definitely want to have it covered by unit tests, to make sure it worked across framework version changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the ouput wrap in the redirected file?  The wrapping that the console does is not by means of line breaks.  In other words this string:

> hello my name is Andrew Hare

would wrap in a skinny console like this:

> hello my nam
>   e is Andrew
>   Hare

but if you were to redirect the output to a file it would be written like this:

> hello my name is Andrew Hare

since there are no true line-breaks in the output.

Comment: Exactly - in a skinny console it would be wrapped in a crappy way. Which is why we're wrapping ourselves (by inserting newlines and appropriate indentation) before outputting to the console.

Obviously this approach also wraps the redirected output, which is what we're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that! Just pass an additional command line parameter that specifies the formatting you want to be applied. It's simpler, cleaner, and easier to understand both by people that will use your app and by people who will work on your code.

Comment: I disagree. Programs should figure things out by themselves to as large an extent as possible, and not ask the user every time.

Comment: Disagree as well. Look at how git behaves. Commands like `git diff` pipe through less and some kind of colorizer unless they are piped or redirected to a file.