# Check if output is redirected

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, console

I have a console application written in C# which processes some data then prints the results. Until the results are available there is a little animation ( / - \ | ) and progress percentage ( xx% ) which is constantly updating.

Obviously if the user redirects the output of my application this will be printed to the text file where output is redirected to. If possible I would like to avoid this.

So is there a way to detect if the output of my application is redirected? 
I am considering only showing the progress indicators when run with a specified parameter, but I'm hoping someone will have a good answer for me.

Comment: Its interesting reading your question three years later and realizing how silly it was :-) if there is anyone reading this ... the correct way to approach this is most certainly to not show the progress bar by default ... only display it when a specific switch is used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine whether Console.Out has been redirected to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743885/how-can-i-determine-whether-console-out-has-been-redirected-to-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Redirected output is totally and wholly outside the scope of the executing program. You **can** however add a commandline option to disable your pretty output so that it can be used redirected too.

**EDIT: You CAN (now)...** with .NET 4.5 onwards (see [Matt Brooks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31982628/1245420)).

Comment: Just as I thought >.< Might just have to go with the cli parameter option.

Comment: What if I want to guess some default settings depending on whether the input goes from console or not? For example, in SQL parser it's good to print the resulting recordset when accepting commands from the keyboard, but be silent when parsing file. Or what if I care to output the Unicode BOM when writing to file? What are the patterns that should be used in these cases?

Comment: @himself: If you want to handle stuff like writing a BOM, then ask for an output parameter. Depending on the OS, you can detect if you're running on a console, but it's convoluted to say the least, and it doesn't work on Windows/C# I don't think. Your simplest bet is to accept a `-q` (quiet) or similar option, or perhaps assume you're getting programmed input if you've got said option enabled to write to a file.

Answer (score 16):

From .NET Framework 4.5 onwards you can use the [`Console.IsOutputRedirected` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect this.

There's also `Console.IsErrorRedirected`.

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out, it soon will be available in the elegant and cross-platform way:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the native method [GetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see if stdout is going to a console or not.

This method is suggested by the remarks in the documentation for [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401.aspx):

> ... determine whether the output handle is a console handle (one method is to call the GetConsoleMode function and check whether it succeeds)...

Comment: Grannted, that means using unsafe native methods... But it's possible.

Comment: Some properties call `GetConsoleMode` and throw on failure, such as `Console.CursorVisible`. That would allow checking for console output without using P/Invoke.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to determine whether or not the content is redirected, I would use Console.WriteLine (or Console.Out.WriteLine) to print your results and Console.Error.Write for your status updates.  The screen output will show properly but not be reflected in the text file.

Comment: Good idea, however it is rather misleading to write non-error data to stderr.

Comment: Misleading, yes, but a common practice all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you can try this:

```
public enum FileType : uint
{
    FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0x0000,
    FILE_TYPE_DISK = 0x0001,
    FILE_TYPE_CHAR = 0x0002,
    FILE_TYPE_PIPE = 0x0003,
    FILE_TYPE_REMOTE = 0x8000,
}

public enum STDHandle : uint
{
    STD_INPUT_HANDLE = unchecked((uint)-10),
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = unchecked((uint)-11),
    STD_ERROR_HANDLE = unchecked((uint)-12),
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static public extern UIntPtr GetStdHandle(STDHandle stdHandle);
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static public extern FileType GetFileType(UIntPtr hFile);

static public bool IsOutputRedirected()
{
    UIntPtr hOutput = GetStdHandle(STDHandle.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    FileType fileType = (FileType)GetFileType(hOutput);
    if (fileType == FileType.FILE_TYPE_CHAR)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

If the standard output is not redirected, the output of the GetFileType() should be 0x0002.
This works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Write("whatever")` (and WriteLine) actually write data to the stream behind `Console.Out`.
To always show a progress bar on the console and not write it to a file, no matter if the output is redirected to a file or not, use the error stream instead:

`Console.Error.Write("<your progress bar>");`

When an application redirects output with the > operator (`DIR C:\*.*>MORE`), only `Console.Out` is redirected and not `Console.Error`